# Filter in Pandas by logic "and"

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

[image]

I would like to take a result with filter city is San Francisco and score > 90, i wrote the code like below:

```
df[df['city'].str.contains('San') and df['score'] > 90]
df
```

however, it show the error is "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." . Can someone assist me on this ?
Thank you

however, it v

Answer (score 2):

Use regex, starts with in the str.contains

```
df[(df['city'].str.contains('^[San]')) & (df['score'] > 90)]
```

Answer (score 1):

or just

```
df[df['city'].str.contains('San') & (df['score'] > 90)]
```